# Set Header row range as Array of header names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to set the header row range as an array of header names.
In VBA I would write `myArray = myRange.Value` where myRange would be the range of the headers in row 1.

I am trying:

```
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ShtName');
var Range = sSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sSheet.getLastColumn());
var Values = []
var Values = Range.getValues();
```

But `Values` does not seem to be an *Array*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `getValues` returns a double array: for example, `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` where 1, 2 is the first row of the range and 3, 4 is the second. This applies even if the range has just one row: the output will be `[[1, 2]]`.

So, in your setup you would use `Values[0]` as the array of headers. The headers are `Values[0][0]`, `Values[0][1]`, and so on.